# React Native crashing in RCTNetworkTask.m

Tags: react-native

I'm getting a pretty consistent crash at in RCTNetworkTask.m at `[self invalidate];` here:

```
- (void)cancel
{
  _status = RCTNetworkTaskFinished;
  id token = _requestToken;
  if (token && [_handler respondsToSelector:@selector(cancelRequest:)]) {
    [_handler cancelRequest:token];
  }
  [self invalidate];
}
```

The inline error shows `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXCI386_GPLFT)`, if that means anything.

I assume this is being thrown when loading some bad image into an `<Image/>` component. I have an `onError` handler on the images, but that doesn't seem to help. I don't have control over most images in my app are supplied by the user.

Is there any way to catch this error before it crashes the app entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be an issue with React Native itself. Fix went into v0.37.

Comment: Were you running 0.36 previously?  I did not have this issue until 0.36.

Comment: I was getting this on 0.34.

Comment: I got this issue in 1.33 :(